# How to speed up score board calculation in rails from large database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

What ways can I speed up total score calculation from about 100k rows users table and 15000k rows scores table database? I already added index to user_id in scores table.
Now, the speed is: 
Rendered users/_user_row.html.erb (3.0ms)
Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1970.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2113ms (Views: 343.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1768.3ms)

What I have is

User_controller:

```
def index
 @users = User.by_total_points.limit(50)
end
```

User.rb model:

```
has_many :points

def self.by_total_points
 joins(:points).group('users.id').order('SUM(points.value) DESC')
end

def total_points
 self.points.sum(:value)
end
```

point.rb model:

```
belongs_to :user
```

Schema.rb

```
create_table "points", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "user_id",    null: false
t.integer  "value",      null: false
t.string   "label",      null: false
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

add_index "points", ["user_id"], name: "index_points_on_user_id", using: :btree

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "first_name",            null: false
t.string   "last_name",             null: false
t.string   "username",   limit: 32, null: false
t.string   "email",                 null: false
t.datetime "created_at",            null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",            null: false
t.integer  "sumscore"
end
```

Comment: are you just trying to calculate the points? or the ranking?

Comment: cache the total points to the user model and add an index on that column

Answer (score 0):

So this is less of a Rails problem, more of a system design problem. If you are trying to just always only get the top 50, you can

1. use [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) and keep a heap of the top 50 players
2. cache that (either in redis, or just a separate table).
3. Everytime when you need to render the score board, you just need to pull that and sort 50 players.

This way, you have insertion time of nlog(n) on 50 records, which is constant asymptotically.

In this system, you will have two scroing tables, or one table, one array in redis. The main table keep all the scores, the cache table or array just keep the top 50.

If you are trying to get all the rankings, you can structure an sorted tree (n-nary) and bucket users into score ranges so that you do do log(n) insertion and read. This is a bit complicated to setup, and I suggest avoiding it unless you have hundreds of write per second updating scores and your app require real time ranking, and you have over 100m users.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the answer is going to be contextual to how often it is hit, how often the points update and how ok it is for the scores to be outdated.

You will probably end up with either caching or a counter.  Just a random stab at it without any context

1. Setup cache in memory and have a cache key for each user for total points
2. Setup cache in memory for the top 50 users and their points
3. When someone updates points update the first cache for that user AND also update the cache if they are now in the top 50

Now instead of hitting the database you can check the cache, your request will now be lighting fast at the expense of doing extra work updating caches.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Extra Note:  Also write a rake task to rebuild these for the case when you lose the cache.